# When I enter the Institute for the first time I can't progress

Tags: fallout-4

On Fallout 4, when I first entered the Institute I got the quest, then I entered the Elevator, and I got down, went in the next elevator to the room with a child in it, and I can't leave. Not sure if it is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. The quest objective says "Enter the Elevator" with a checkmark next to it, but then nothing else. I sided with the Railroad, if that affects it

Comment: Did you finish the dialog with the child and the one with the man coming after?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured it out on my own. I had to aim at the child in a specific way for some reason, but it turns out you just talk to him.